# UBI volume read fails

Tags: c++, linux, flash

I am trying to read a ubi volume in linux environment UBI volume is raw volume.

```
    char * arr = new char[5];
int fd = open("/dev/UBI0_1", O_RDONLY);
if(fd)
{
     int bytes = read(fd,arr,5);
     if(bytes)
     printf("read was success\n");
     else
     printf("read failed\n");
 }
```

I am getting read failed. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Just for experiment, I tried ioctl with volume update command and did write,it worked.

Comment: Use e.g. `strerror` to print what the error is.

Comment: Also, your conditions `if (fd)` and `if (bytes)` are flawed, remember that `open` and `read` returns `-1` on failure, and that's considered "true" (only zero is false, anything non-zero is true). Now, read [the `read` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and see what it means when `read` returns zero.

Comment: got your point, but in  general will read system call works on UBI volumes..??

Answer (score 0):

I think `mtd_read` should be called to read ubi (mtd_read is a function of the mtd lib libmtd.a). You really can call `read` to do the same thing, but it may be a little complex.